# How to run commands with sudo privilege using pysftp module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko, pysftp

I am using pysftp module in my module to execute commands in remote server with sudo privilege with out prompting the password.

I tried in many ways, but no success.

```
import pysftp
server = pysftp.Connection('169.254.204.32', username='test', password='root123')

str_t = server.execute('sudo -S fdisk -l')

for i in  str_t:
    print i

# Finally Close the Server Connection
server.close()
```

Earlier, i used paramiko module, there i can able to run the commands with SUDO privileges by using send() functionality.

Currently, i am trying with the pysftp module, but no success. Could any one help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP-server don't allow system commands. I think pysftp.execute() allows internal sftp commands only (like get, put and so on).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried using some commands server.execute('ls  -lart') , ifconfig -a . Commands execute and providing the output. But some specific commands which requires "sudo previleages" giving error as permission denied. Even i tried with out pysftp  module, it is giving same error as permission denied. So i can say we can execute commands using pysftp.execute()

Comment: I'm sure your commands will execute local. Similar to the sftp command "!ls" See help of command line sftp client. sftp is only file transfer.
You need shell access (ssh) or something like rpc. Or try zeromq [link](http://zeromq.org/).

Comment: You're wrong, see my answer

Comment: My post refers to a "SFTP server only". For example, if in sshd "ForceCommand internal-sftp" is configured.

With an ordinary, standard configured SSH server, SFTP is enabled in addition to the SSH protocol. Then you can execute commands on the server via SSH, but not via SFTP protocol. In this way you are right.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you have to use these lines of code:

```
my_password = "root123"
str_t = server.execute("echo " + my_password " | sudo -S fdisk -l")
```